# What's more efficient? Read and Write If... or always write to db?

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I have a database table, that has a column, which is being updated frequently (relatively).

The question is:

Is it more efficient to avoid always writing to the database, by reading the object first (`SELECT ... WHERE`), and comparing the values, to determine if an update is even necessary

or always just issue an update (`UPDATE ... WHERE`) without checking what's the current state.

I think that the first approach would be more hassle, as it consists of two DB operations, instead of just one, but we could also avoid an unnecessary write.

I also question if we should even think about this, as our db will most likely not reach the 100k records in this table anytime soon, so even if the update would be more costly, it wouldn't be an issue, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

The database is PostgreSQL 9.6

Comment: I'm not sure what you asked but Postgres can handle 100K records easily. You should continue with your product and check how is your database perform every now and then. If optimization needed there start with optimize your queries and postgres conf.

Comment: Thanks @OrDuan I too have a feeling that this optimisation wouldn't bring much to the table at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will avoid I/O load on the database if you only perform the updates that are necessary.

You can include the test with the `UPDATE`, like in

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mycol = 'avalue'
WHERE id = 42
  AND mycol <> 'avalue';
```

The only downside is that triggers will not be called unless the value really changes.